# How to escape / in filename dynamically in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, escaping

I have a program which writes to certain files, where file name is generated on the fly and can contain special characters at random.

Whenever there is a `/` in these special characters, code considers it to be a OS path separator for linux.

How can I escape this dynamically?

Demonstration of what I am running into:

```
import random
special_chars = "$^&%*^(&/"
selected = random.choice(special_chars)
#selected = "/"
with open(__file__ + "%s.txt" % selected) as f:
    f.write("Hello")
```

Runs very well when it is any other character than `/`, but when you set selected as `/`:
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./a.py", line 7, in <module>
    with open(__file__ + "%s.txt" % selected, 'w') as f:
IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: './a.py/.txt'
```

python 2.7 only please.

Comment: `/` is not a legal character to have in a filename

Comment: @Nullman, I think you might be right. I didnt think of it this way.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to replace one character, just use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str.replace), for instance `name.replace('/', '-')`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the @Nullman said, `/` is not a valid character for filenames in Linux:

```
$ touch a

$ touch a/b/c.txt
touch: cannot touch 'a/b/c.txt': Not a directory
```

You should never use `/` and `\` symbols in filenames because it has many unexpected results. For example:

**Linux terminal:**

```
$ touch a\b\c
$ ls
abc
```

**IPython 3:**

```
In [1]: with open('a\b\c', 'w') as f:
   ...:     f.write(' ')
   ...:     

In [2]: ls
a?\c
```